# permissons: can't create/delete folder in file manager when www-data is a user

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, permissions

I have permissions issue with www-data (apache) and just a linux user.
In my www folder is wp/

If I set:
`sudo chown -R user.www-data wp/`

My wordpress shows info it can write to a file, but if I set `sudo chown -R www-data.user wp/` then WP works fine, but I can't create/delete folders/files in that directory in a file manager.
I've also added user to www-data group and www-data to user group, but it doesn't help. Still the same problem. What I'm doing wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into chmod instead of chown.
Also, when using either of those commands, the syntax is user:group.

One solution is to chown -R user:www-data wp/
And then chmod -R 775 wp/

That will give both the user and the group www-data full access to the folder.